# Android - Enum method set two data types for each option

Tags: java, android, enums

I have this enum type method, right now it returns one color as an int for each option but I want each option to return one color as an int and one string. Here is what I have, I would really appreciate some help so that it will also return a string value:

```
enum Direction {
    NORHT(Color.RED), SOUTH(Color.YELLOW);

    Direction(int c) {
        color = c;
    }

    private int color;

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

So how could I edit this to also return a sting let say "getting colder" for north and "getting warmer" for south?

Its this line Im having tourble with, not sure where to add the string.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Just follow what's already there and build on it. Add a string field, a string parameter to the constructor, pass the string to the constructors up where you declare the values, add a getter for it. Just like the current int, but a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to simply add another parameter to the constructor of the enum and pass it along when defining each of your values for the enum.

```
   enum Direction {
        NORTH(Color.RED, "Getting Colder"), 
        SOUTH(Color.YELLOW, "Getting Warmer");

        Direction(int c, String m) {
            color = c;
            message = m;
        }

        private int color;
        private String message;

        public int getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public String getMessage(){
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: great except remove the () from this line for it to be correct `return message();`